# How do you access react hooks in multiple components? What am I doing wrong with my react hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, object-destructuring

Im trying to pass a state value into a component. Why is it working in one component and not working in another component in the same folder?

I have the hooks in here. Im trying to access "currentGuess". In this function I initialize the state of currentGuess to "", then the next part just sets the "currentGuess" to whatever you type in.

----------------------**/src/hooks/useWordle.js**----------------------

```
const useWordle = (solution) => {
  const [currentGuess, setCurrentGuess] = useState("");

  /* OTHER UNNECESSARY CODE TO QUESTION */

  const handleInput = ({ key }) => {
    if (key === "Enter") {
      if (turn > 5) {
        console.log("You used all your guesses!");
        return;
      }
      if (history.includes(currentGuess)) {
        console.log("You already tried that word!");
        return;
      }
      if (currentGuess.length !== 5) {
        console.log("Word must be 5 characters long!");
        return;
      }
      const formatted = formatGuessWord();
      console.log(formatted);
    }
    if (key === "Backspace") {
      setCurrentGuess((state) => {
        return state.slice(0, -1);
      });
    }

    if (/^[a-zA-z]$/.test(key))
      if (currentGuess.length < 5) {
        setCurrentGuess((state) => {
          return state + key;
        });
      }
  };
  return {
    currentGuess,
    handleInput,
  };
};

export default useWordle;
```

I can use it in here like this and it works no problem:

----------------------**src/components/Wordle.js**----------------------

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import useWordle from "../hooks/wordleHooks.js";

function Wordle({ solution }) {
  const { currentGuess, handleInput } = useWordle(solution);
  console.log("currentGuess=", currentGuess);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keyup", handleInput);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("keyup", handleInput);
  });

  return <div>Current guess: {currentGuess}</div>;
}

export default Wordle;
```

I thought this line was what allowed me to use "currentGuess". I destructured it.

> const { currentGuess, handleInput } = useWordle(solution);

However when I place that line in this code, "currentGuess" comes out undefined or empty.

----------------------**/src/components/Key.js**----------------------

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { AppContext } from "../App";
import useWordle from "../hooks/wordleHooks.js";

export default function Key({ keyVal, largeKey }) {
  const { onSelectLetter, onDeleteKeyPress, onEnterKeyPress } =
    useContext(AppContext);
  const { currentGuess } = useWordle();

  const handleTypingInput = () => {
    console.log("Key.js - Key() - handleTypingInput() - {currentGuess}= ", {
      currentGuess,
    }); // COMES OUT "Object { currentGuess: "" }"
  };
```

If you made it this far thank you very much. Im new to this and hoping someone who knows what they are doing can see some glaring flaw in the code I can fix. You don't even have to solve it for me but can you point me in the right direction? How do I make the "currentGuess" variable/state be accessible in the **Key.js** component?

Comment: For future reference, see: [How do I create a React Stack Snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/979052). It makes it a lot easier to quickly run the code, when it's an interactive snippet, therefore giving you better answers.

Comment: can you do that when its multiple files/components all over the place though? How do you add a bunch of files and child components passing stuff to each other in the one JS block they give you? Can I just upload to github and convert it that way?

Answer (score 1):

Hooks are meant to share behavior, not state. The call to `useWordle` in your `Wordle` component creates a completely different variable in memory for `currentGuess` than the call to `useWordle` in the `Key` component (remember, after all, that hooks are just regular old functions!). In other words, you have two completely separate versions of `currentGuess` floating around, one in each component.

If you'd like to share state, use the [Context API](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/01/introduction-react-context-api/), use a state management library (such [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/README.html), etc.), or just [lift state up](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components#lifting-state-up-by-example).

Comment: might be a stupid question, but in the "lift state up" link the examples use class components and a lot of "this". Can you still do it when using functional components?

Comment: @SpoonyLuv absolutely. I'll edit my answer with an example as soon as I can.

Comment: @SpoonyLuv realized I never got to this, see https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components#lifting-state-up-by-example